# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2: attribute 'android:versionCode' not found

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I've updated Android Studio to the latest canary build and now I can't run my app.

Every time when I try to build the project I get the following error:

```
Error:F:\...\**app_name**\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-support\debug\slice_0\AndroidManifest.xml:2 attribute 'android:versionCode' not found
```

I tried to manually open the file and the attribute is clearly there:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="****"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0"
      split="lib_slice_0_apk">
</manifest>
```

I've tried to clean the project, invalidate cache, restart android studio but nothing helped.

This is my `build.gradle (app)` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "****"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem!

Comment: Sam problem  atfer the upgrade

Comment: Adding to the manifest worked for me package="..." 
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" > without disabling InstantRun

Comment: Even when I add `versionCode` and `versionName` explicitly to the `<manifest>`, I sometimes get the error. Then clicking on *Refresh all gradle projects* in the *Gradle projects* view helps

Answer (score 16):

This issue is strictly related to Instant Run. Workaround: disable it inside `File` -> `Settings/Preferences`. This will at least allow you to run your app in the Canary version of AS.

Comment: fixed it for me thanks, I hope someone would report this to google

Comment: @LordFlash yes I mentioned that.

Comment: Also @Viper Alpha from comments seems to have another option. Not sure if his solution would influence anything project-related though.

Answer (score 5):

This bug is solved since Android Studio 3.0 Canary 6, just update android studio and all SDK components and restart Android Studio.

Tested on:

Build #AI-171.4163606, built on July 7, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-884-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

Answer (score 4):

Simply **invalidating the caches** did the job for me.

> File > Invalidate Caches & Restart

No need to disable *Instant Run* or manually delete any build folders.

Comment: Instant run disabling was the solution dude.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me is a combination of what robin and SamboyCoding said.

1. Clean Project from build menu
2. Rebuild Project from build menu

Then I could launch the app for testing without problems.

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was going into my project folder, and deleting the "build" folder, to force gradle to recompile everything. I also deleted the "gradle" folder, but had to recreate it manually because AS didn't, but I don't think it was this that fixed it.

Comment: Deleting the `build` folder doesn't help. Just tried it.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same. I tried either rebuild the project or change build gradle a bit(e.g change a versionName) and sync, then mostly the issue is temporarily gone.

Answer (score 2):

The fastest workaround that works for me in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 is to add the `versionCode` and `versionName` attributes, and when the error occurs, I just change it to any other value (e.g. `1.0` to `1.1` and back). Then the app starts fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          package="com.XXX"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

As for 6/9/2017 [Android Studio 3.0 Canary 3](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-3-is-now.html) the bug still exists. After trying all mentioned ways to fix this, the one that works is to:

1. Clean Project
2. Build Project
3. Disable/Re-enable Instant Run feature
   or
4. Reload Android Studio.

In case of the error - suggesting to send report to Google via **Help > Report Instant Run Issue..**, also create a bug report in Groups. Don't forget to link this StackOverlow page - may be this way Google will fix this annoying bug fast.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. So I tried the stable version 2.3.1 of android studio. Then there come a question if I want to use the Android studios SDK, I select this.

Try to run the app, a Gradle error come up, which request minimum Android Studio 3.0.

I start Android Studio 3.0 C2 again, the question regarding the SDK come up again, but then the app compiles and the versionCode error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild the project 
and restart android studio.
It will work.

Answer (score 0):

After cleaning and rebulding I disabled instant run and re-enabled it and the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Update Android studio to Canary 3. They solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

Every time I get this following error:

`Error:D:\StudioProjects\yoda\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-support\debug\slice_0\AndroidManifest.xml:2 attribute 'android:versionCode' not found`

I'd like to delete `D:\StudioProjects\yoda\app\build` folder, then select Build\Rebuild Project, and everything will become all right.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was enough to delete .gradle folder in the root folder of the project

Answer (score 0):

open the manifest file & close it.
if still not working: rebuild, open manifest file & close it, -> RUN