# How to solve Instant Run on Android Studio Canary 5, 6 and 7

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.0

Since I upgraded to Android Studio Canary 5 I have had issues with Instant Run, it gives me the following error when Instant Run is enabled:

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
Error:C:\..etc.\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-support\debug\dependencies\AndroidManifest.xml:2 resource string/app_build_version_name (aka com.itbackyard.iels.client:string/app_build_version_name) not found
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Error:com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Error:com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Error:com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 link failed:
Information:BUILD FAILED in 1m 29s
Information:8 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

My only solution was to disable Instant Run from settings. What I was able to find is this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486142/androidversioncode-not-found-after-update/44488166#comment76743286_44488166) without a solution so far.

Any idea if this is still a bug or is there any workaround till it gets fixed?

Here is my version information:

```
Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5
Build #AI-171.4141229, built on June 28, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-884-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

---

**Edit**
I have now updated it to

```
Android Studio 3.0 Canary 6
Build #AI-171.4163606, built on July 7, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-884-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

And updated to Canary 7

```
Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7
Build #AI-171.4182969, built on July 14, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-884-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0
```

Still the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way:

What I did was create an empty new project in Android Studio 3.0 Canary 7, it does not have this behavior. I compared the new empty project default `build.gradle (Module: app)` with my existing project that has the mentioned problem.

Of course, this can differ from case to case, but in my case, I used a variable to update `versionName` and it worked previously without any issues, but not on Andriod Studio 3. Therefore I corrected the lines, `Sync` and `Rebuild` the problem was gone.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line gradle.properties file. it work for me

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

[Android Studio 3.0 Canary 5](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html)

If your build fails due to resource processing issue. To temporarily disable AAPT, set android.enableAapt2=false in your gradle.properties file.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, what does this line do?

Comment: thank you for your update, but it did not help in this case. (: so far would only work if I disabled Instant Run

Comment: I know, but this android.enableAapt2=false did not help in this case, it is time killer ;( I agree